# Truncating A List In OCaml

Tags: queue, ocaml

Is it possible for me to truncate a list after a given element in OCaml without the use of recursion?

```
let truncate (elt: 'a) (q: 'a queue) : unit =
```

I can think of potentially how to do this using nested pattern matching... looking for a better way without rec

Comment: It's hard to get any kind of handle on this question. There's no type `'a queue` in OCaml, and there's no reason whatsoever to avoid using recursion. There's also no way to match an arbitrary sized structure with a pattern.

Comment: the type 'a queue is 'a list ref? It is essentially a list? There is also another type of queue that is a record with mutable head and tail: type 'a queue = { mutable head: 'a qnode option; mutable tail: 'a qnode option }

Answer (score 0):

A list node contains all the next elements.

Hence, to truncate a list, you need to create a new list that contains only the first elements (this is the only way to get the desired truncated list).

Hence, the type of the function that you are looking for is

```
let truncate : 'a -> 'a list -> 'a list 
= fun elt queue -> ...
```

As Jeffrey Scofield says, there is no point in avoiding recursion.

Comment: What if I want to edit the queue without producing a new queue? This is my attempt so far:                                                                                                             let rec clear (q: 'a queue): unit = begin match !q with | [] -> () | hd :: tl -> !q <- []; end 
 
let rec truncate (elt: 'a) (q: 'a queue) : unit =begin match !q with
  | [] -> ()
  | hd :: tl -> if hd == elt then clear tl
  end

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you *really want to*, you can do lots of things. Have two examples of technical avoidance of recursion, and then what I think you might've actually been looking for:

```
let truncate1 elt list = (* tedious iteration version *)
  let list = ref list in
  let r = ref [] in
  while !list <> [] do
    r := List.hd !list :: !r;
    if List.hd !list = elt then list := [] else
      list := List.tl !list
  done;
  List.rev !r

let truncate2 elt list = (* let's not mind how List.find does it version *)
  let r = ref [] in
  ignore (List.find (fun x -> r := x :: !r; x = elt) list);
  List.rev !r

(* this is more what you're looking for? version *)
type 'a mutcons = { mutable head : 'a; mutable tail : 'a mutlist }
and 'a mutlist = Nil | Cons of 'a mutcons

let rec mutlist_iter f = function
  | Nil -> ()
  | Cons k -> f k; mutlist_iter f k.tail

let rec truncate3 elt mlist =
  mutlist_iter (fun k -> if k.head = elt then k.tail <- Nil) mlist
```

Where the last walks over a mutable list and mutates the current cell to be the last of the list if it contains a given element.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a destructive data structure, so with mutable values and a while you can do it.

The queue interface is the good one. Pop values until you find the desire element :

```
Pseudo alorithm
Do 
    Current = queue.pop myqueue
Until (current = desiredvalue) or (queue.isempty myqueue)

 Return myqueue
```